# Is there a way to automatically check npm modules dependencies and rebuild if one of them is updated?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, dependencies, publish, rebuild

I have a Vue app that will be deployed through Gitlab CI/CD.
This has a lot of npm modules dependencies like

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@myPersonalRegistry/foo-module": "^1.0.75111",
  "@myPersonalRegistry/bar-module": "^1.0.9",
  "moment": "^2.27.0",
  "vue": "^2.6.10",
},
```

Let's say that my bar-module is updated (some bug fixed or new feature), and it is published with a new version 1.1.0.
The only way to my published app to use the new version is to rebuild that app?

I want to know if there is a possibility that the app can (maybe from time to time), check for new dependencies versions and automatically rebuild if found one, maybe some CI configuration.

Thank you!

Comment: I think that there is no gitlab feature like this, but you could maybe have an external cron job that check your current node modules used versions to detect change and so trigger a new build pipeline via api